# MATLAB like structure in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm new to Python. I would like to use MATLAB-like structure in python. I already see several solutions in stackoverflow using dictionary, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611197/matlab-structure-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922586/matlab-struct-array-to-python). However, I feel like the dummy object approach in the code below is more MATLAB-like and more natural to use since we don't need the double quotes for names of attributes. The use case for me is sololy to wrap several objects together in a casual way, such that some of the functions don't need to have a long list of arguments. For example, the last function below only has two arguments rather than 6.

My question is: now I have to define the dummy class Structure in my script. Is it necessary? If many of my scripts need to use it, I will have to put it somewhere that all my functions can access. Is there a built-in "dummy class" already existed I can just use?

```
import numpy as np

class Structure:
  pass

def construct_network():
  net = Structure()
  net.n = 100;
  net.Weights = np.random.rand(net.n, net.n)
  net.biases = np.random.rand(net.n, 1)
  return net

def a_function_operate_on_two_nets(net1, net2):
  # Use the net1 and net2 here.
```

Comment: Look into `namedtuple`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python3.3 added [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) which is what you're looking for.  For earlier versions of python, you may have to rely on something built for a similar (close enough) task -- e.g. [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace).

And, of course there is always `collections.namedtuple` if you actually want something *structured* (which is usually preferred to something unstructured).

Comment: Interesting. You answered both my current question and some questions I will likely ask in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You created this structure in a file. For example put that code in struct.py
then in another python script just write `from struct.py import Structure`
or if you created other structures you can import all that clases using `from struct.py import *`